# No qualifying bean of type 'mypackage.repository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate

Tags: spring-boot, junit4

I have a test class in Junit4 that needs to use NutrientListService.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ApplicationContext.class)
public class CalculationTests {

    private NutrientListService nutrientService;

    @Test
    public void someTest()
        Result re = Calculator.calculate(response, nutrientService)
}
```

I was getting a null nutrientService, so I tried to set up an ApplicationContext.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("myservice")
@ComponentScan("myrepository")
public class ApplicationContext {

    @Autowired
    NutrientListService nutrientService;
}
```

However, I get

`Error creating bean with name 'nutrientListService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'nutrientListRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'repositories.NutrientListRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}`

This is the service:

```
@Service
@Component
public class NutrientListService {
    @Autowired
    private NutrientListRepository repo;
}
```

And the repository:

```
@Repository
public interface NutrientListRepository extends MongoRepository<MyClass, String> {

    MyClass findByID(String ID);
}
```

Any ideas to wire the service properly? I need to pass it for calculation as it is one of the parameters. Do I have to use an application context class or the application-context.xml (which I could not find)? What would be the least obscure way to do this? I thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("myservice")
@ComponentScan("myrepository")
public class ApplicationContext {
    @Bean
    NutrientListService nutrientService(){
      new NutrientListService()
    }
}
```

And then call the Bean with @Autowired

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ApplicationContext.class)
public class CalculationTests {

    @Autowired
    NutrientListService nutrientService

    @Test
    public void someTest()
        Result re = Calculator.calculate(response, nutrientService)
}
```